# ng-show/ng-if doesn't update dom height immediately

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a long div which is hide/show by ng-hide.
here is a sample based on ionic [demo](http://codepen.io/leonz/full/bEqbKM/).

Click the button to make the longDiv show or hide. If you try to scroll the page immediately after hiding or showing it. 
sometimes you can find the page can scroll down even after longDiv hide. And sometimes page can not scroll down even after longDiv show. But if you wait for seconds, then try to scroll the page, the scroll bar can match the page's actual height.

Html:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="test.show_detail=!test.show_detail">{{test.show_detail}}</button>
  <div ng-show='test.show_detail'>
    <div ng-repeat='i in test.list'>
      {{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

JS:

```
.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
     $scope.test = {};
     $scope.test.show_detail = true;
     $scope.test.list = [];
     for(i=0; i< 1000; i++){
       $scope.test.list.push(i);
     }
}
```

This issue is very easy to reproduce if there are complex template content in the long div container.

Is there any method to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know Ionic well enough to say why it updates so slow, but you should be able to solve it either by activating native scrolling with the `overflow-scroll` attribute:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="controller" overflow-scroll="true">
```

Or by injecting `$ionicScrollDelegate` in your controller and calling `resize` manually:

```
$scope.toggle = function() {
  $scope.test.show_detail = !$scope.test.show_detail;
  $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
};
```

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: My last update is wrong. I delete it. overflow-scroll="true" and $ionicScrollDelegate both can work. if we use overflow-scroll=true, it may cause other issues, so   $ionicScrollDelegate is better in my situation. @tasseKATT

Comment: It's a good solution.  Looking at Ionic itself there's a 'self.hintResize = ionic.debounce(function() { self.resize(); }, 1000, true);' as part of 'ionic.views.Scroll', meaning that Ionic debounces the resizing for a full second.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is this:

```
<button ng-click="handleClick()">{{test.show_detail}}</button>
```

Your controller would now look something like this:

```
.controller('controller', function ($scope, $timeout, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.test = {};
    $scope.test.show_detail = true;
    $scope.test.list = [];

    for(i=0; i< 1000; i++){
        $scope.test.list.push(i);
    };

    $scope.handleClick = function(){
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Loading...'
        });

        $scope.test.show_detail = !$scope.test.show_detail;

        $timeout(function(){
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        } , 3000);  
    };
}
```

Here's the breakdown of what I did:

- added two new dependencies (`$timeout`, and `$ionicLoading`) to your controller
- added a function `handleClick` which shows a loading message for 3 seconds and then it hides it

You would probably have to play with the proper timeout and while this certainly isn't a perfect solution, I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Nikola. This is so dirty, I can not accept it.