# ng click show div ng-repeat item scroll failed

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am having a problem with click on an item within a ng-repeat. What happens is that when I click on an icon, it should display a div that is hidden, for each item there is a div. The problem is that if indeed shows hidden divs but the scroll fails, it costs a lot to go down all the information. I made a codepen with sample code.

```
<ion-view view-title="Fechas">
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-ios-arrow-back button-icon"></i>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-content>
    <div class="list" style="margin-bottom: -1px;height:100%;" ng-repeat="fecha in torneo.fechas">
        <a class="item item-icon-right">
        {{fecha.fecha_nombre}}
            <div class="buttons">
                <i class="icon" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" ng-class="{'icon ion-chevron-up': showDetails, 'icon ion-chevron-down': !showDetails}"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div ng-show="showDetails" id="elementoTorneo">
            <div class="item item-image" style="border-bottom-width: 0px;">
                <img class="full-image" style="border-bottom-width: 0px;" ng-src="{{(torneo.torneo_afiche != '') ? 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+torneo.torneo_afiche : './img/sin_afiche.png'}}">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row" ng-show="showDetails" style="    padding: 1px !important;">
                <div class="item item-divider" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;background-color:#6ca4ea;color:white;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 10px;">
                    Club
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col" >
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-location"></i>
                        <p>{{fecha.fecha_club_nombre}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="    padding: 1px !important;">
                <div class="item item-divider" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;background-color:#6ca4ea;color:white;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 10px;">
                    Informaci&oacute;n general
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col col-50" >
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-calendar"></i>
                        <p>Inicio fecha</p>
                        <p class="valor_negrita">{{fecha.fecha_inicio}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-calendar"></i>
                        <p>Termino fecha</p>
                        <p class="valor_negrita">{{fecha.fecha_termino}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-people"></i>
                        <p>Categorías</p>
                        <p ng-repeat="categoria in categorias_split">- {{categoria}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="padding: 1px !important;">
                <div class="item item-divider" style="width: 100%;text-align: center;background-color:#6ca4ea;color:white;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 10px;">
                    Inscripci&oacute;n
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-calendar"></i>
                        <p>Inicio inscripción</p>
                        <p class="valor_negrita">{{fecha.fecha_inscripcion_inicio}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-50">
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-calendar"></i>
                        <p>Termino inscripción</p>
                        <p class="valor_negrita">{{fecha.fecha_inscripcion_termino}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <a class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-cash"></i>
                        <p>Valor inscripción</p>
                        <p class="valor_negrita">${{ReplaceNumberWithPoints(fecha.fecha_valor_inscripcion)}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row"  style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="col" style="margin: 0px;">
                    <div class="item item-torneo">
                        <i class="icon ion-man"></i><p>Coordinador</p>
                        <p>{{fecha.fecha_nombre_coordinador}} {{fecha.fecha_apellido_coordinador}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/gwXZEm)

If you notice, by clicking on the icon shown the div but costs down at the end, we must insist a good time or make several clicks and do not understand why.

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605039/ng-show-ng-if-doesnt-update-dom-height-immediately)
solution in another forum post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $ionicScrollDelegate .resize() function like;

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').resize();
```

check this codepen code;
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjOXmO